# Can we add fields to summary section in purchase order

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How can i edit the Summary section in the purchase order record i.e., can i add extra fields to that section 
Screencast:http://screencast.com/t/B4WWUvQN

Answer (score 2):

The basic answer is No.  Not if you follow NetSuites guidelines about DOM manipulation.  With that said, you can just a client-side javascript library to access the table (class:"totallingtable") that holder the TR's for the fields.  I would not use the below code in production, it's just an example you can run in your browser console to see it work.

```
          jQuery('.totallingtable').append('<tr><td><div data-field-type="currency" class="uir-field-wrapper"><span class="smalltextnolink uir-label " id="sit_custom_fs_lbl_uir_label"><span style="" class="smalltextnolink" id="sit_custom_fs_lbl"><a onmouseout="this.className=\'smalltextnolink\'; " onmouseover="this.className=\'smalltextul\'; return true;" class="smalltextnolink" onclick="return nlFieldHelp(\'TRAN_PURCHORD\',\'total\', this)" style="cursor:help" href="javascript:void(&quot;help&quot;)" title="What\'s this?" tabindex="-1">CUSTOM</a></span></span><span class="uir-field inputreadonly">FIELD</span></div></td><td></td></tr>');
```